# No consigo que se cargue una imagen y después otra

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
        function cambiarImagen(){
```

> Contiene mi array de imagenes

```
            var imagenes = new Array();
            imagenes[0]="1.jpg";
            imagenes[1]="2.jpg";
```

> Muestra mis imagenes aleatoriamente

```
            var imagenesAleatorias = Math.floor(Math.random*imagenes.length);
```

> Con el método de abajo intento cambiar la src de img(HTML) por mi array de imagenes que va aleatoriamente

```
  document.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src', imagenes[imagenesAleatorias]);       
        }

        function tiempoCambio(){
```

> Se me cambia la imagen cada 1 segundo

```
            setInterval(cambiarImagen(), 1000);
        }
```

> CÓDIGO HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practica2</title>
</head>
<body onload="tiempoCambio();">``

> No me aperece ninguna imagen, mi intención es que se cargue una, se cargue la página y cargue otra imagen (que vaya de una en una)

    <img src="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En este caso al usar Math.random, debes indicar que es un metodo Math.random()

```
var imagenesAleatorias = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagenes.length);
```

Adicionalmente, al usar la función setInterval puedes hacerlo usando una referencia a la función, sin necesidad de agregar los paréntesis

```
setInterval(cambiarImagen, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que `Math.random()` es una función por lo cual tiene que tener el `()` al final.

```js
function cambiarImagen() {
  var imagenes = new Array();
  imagenes[0] = "1.jpg";
  imagenes[1] = "2.jpg";
  var imagenesAleatorias = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagenes.length);
  console.log(imagenesAleatorias);
  document.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src', imagenes[imagenesAleatorias]);
}

function tiempoCambio() {
  setInterval(cambiarImagen(), 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Practica2</title>
</head>

<body onload="tiempoCambio();">
  <img>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ya ves, días rayandome por una tonteria en la que no me habia fijado jajaja gracias hombre

Comment: dale men, ntp :D

Answer (score 0):

ademas de lo que te comentaron del `Math.random()` tampoco deberias ejecutar `cambiarImagen` en el `setInterval` , esto hara que se ejecute una sola vez , lo comento porque pusiste que necesitabas una carga tras otra , por supuesto queda a tu criterio limpiar el temporizador cuando lo requieras

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```js
function cambiarImagen() {
  var imagenes = new Array();
  imagenes[0] = "1.jpg";
  imagenes[1] = "2.jpg";
  var imagenesAleatorias = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagenes.length);
  console.log(imagenesAleatorias);
  document.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src', imagenes[imagenesAleatorias]);
}

function tiempoCambio() {
  setInterval(cambiarImagen, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Practica2</title>
</head>

<body onload="tiempoCambio();">
  <img>
</body>

</html>
```